# How to make two scrollable if overflow divs inside a fixed container?

Tags: html, css

Here's my JSfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tan3j6ja/2/

I'm trying to make a page wrap that is fixed with two divs inside that scroll when content is hidden. Even though the content is clearly hidden it won't scroll.

Edit: I want them to scroll independently.

```
.page-wrap {
background-color: #fff;
margin: auto;
margin-top: 60px;
width: 500px;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
top: 20px
}

.grid {
display: flex;
align-items: flex-start;
}

.is-half-1 {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.is-half-2 {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
   overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I believe you need to set a height to your two divs in order for them to scroll properly. Because in the JSFiddle that you provided, their height is set to auto because they're as tall as the content inside of them makes them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to you not setting the actual height, so the overflow doesn't know to actually scroll. Adding pixel heights to both divs resolved the issue.

```css
.page-wrap {
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 60px;
  width: 500px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 20px
}

.grid {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.is-half-1 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 300px;
  display: block;
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.is-half-2 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 500px;
  display: block;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.small-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 10px;
}

.field-input {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 5px 0;
  padding-left: 3px;
  font-size: 15px;
  height: 26px;
}

li {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-wrap">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="is-half-1">
      <h1>Search</h1>
      <input class="field-input" />
      <input class="field-input" />
      <input class="field-input" />
      <input class="field-input" />
      <input class="field-input" />
      <input class="field-input" />
      <input class="field-input" />
      <input class="field-input" />
      <input class="field-input" />
      <input class="field-input" />
    </div>
    <div class="is-half-2">
      <div class="small-container">
        <h1>Results</h1>
        <li>Result</li>
        <li>Result</li>
        <li>Result</li>
        <li>Result</li>
        <li>Result</li>
        <li>Result</li>
        <li>Result</li>
        <li>Result</li>
        <li>Result</li>
        <li>Result</li>
        <li>Result</li>
        <li>Result</li>
        <li>Result</li>
        <li>Result</li>
        <li>Result</li>
        <li>Result</li>
        <li>Result</li>
        <li>Result</li>
        <li>Result</li>
        <li>Result</li>
        <li>Result</li>
        <li>Result</li>
        <li>Result</li>
        <li>Result</li>
        <li>Result</li>
        <li>Result</li>
        <li>Result</li>
        <li>Result</li>
        <li>Result</li>
        <li>Result</li>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Trasiva's solution I found a way to make make it scroll to the end of the list and make it cut off by the bottom of the window so that the window can be any height. I put position: absolute on the scrolling div and set the height to 100%.